# My Array Returns 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function and I am using the array_walk function to use the Title function to scan the values in the Array [link] and put it in the [title] of the corresponding array

For example The Qlick => [link] => "http://www.theqlick.com"
                           [title] => The Qlick

```
    $links = Array();

$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  

// grabs the urls from URL 
$file  = file_get_html($URL);
foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement) 
{
    $abs_url = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);
    if (!empty($abs_url))
        $links[] = $abs_url;
}

  function Titles() {
  global $links;
  $str = implode('',array_map('file_get_contents',$links));
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

  $titles = Array();
    if( strlen( $str )>0 ) {
  $titles[] = preg_match_all( "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $str, $titles );
  return $title;   
  return $links;
  } }


  $newArray = array();


  $title = array_walk($links, 'Titles');
  foreach($links as $key => $val ){
$newArray[$key] = array( 'link' => $val, 'title' => $title);
 }
 print_r($newArray);

My result when var_dump is used:
  array(2) {



 [0]=>
  array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
      }



  [1]=>
  array(6) {
[0]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[1]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
    }

    }
   array(2) {
   [0]=>
     array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
       }


  [1]=>
 array(6) {
[0]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[1]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
    }
    }


  array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
     }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
   [0]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[1]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
     }
     }

    array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
      }
  [1]=>
   array(6) {
[0]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[1]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
     }
     }
    array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
     }
   [1]=>
   array(6) {
  [0]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[1]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
    }
    }
  array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(6) {
[0]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[1]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
[2]=>
string(68) "<title> Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival </title>"
[3]=>
string(24) "<title> Welcome </title>"
[4]=>
string(27) "<title> Qlick Kids </title>"
[5]=>
string(26) "<title> The Qlick </title>"
    }

  [1]=>
  array(6) {
   [0]=>
   string(11) " The Qlick "
   [1]=>

 string(11) " The Qlick "
[2]=>
string(53) " Welcome to Festival Freaks | Home to Leeds Festival "
[3]=>
string(9) " Welcome "
[4]=>
string(12) " Qlick Kids "
[5]=>
string(11) " The Qlick "
    }
    }


   Array
   ( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/index.php
        [title] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/qlickdates.php
        [title] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/festivalfreaks.html
        [title] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/2kcm.php
        [title] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/index3.php
        [title] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/index2.php
        [title] => 1
    )

       )
```

Comment: For one thing, you've got two returns, one after another. The second one will never be reached. For another, the first thing you're returning is `$title`, which is never initialised.

Comment: how should i use $title?

Comment: I think you probably need a line like: `$title = $titles[1]`. But you should probably add some debugging to make sure that that's picking up what you think it is.

Comment: can u show me an example in an answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the end of your function to this:

```
if( strlen( $str )>0 ) {
    $titles = Array();
    preg_match_all( "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $str, $titles );
    if (count($titles) > 1) {
        return $titles[1];   
    }
}

return '';
```

`preg_match_all` returns the number of matches. This will return the first match you find, or an empty string if there's no title or no text to search.

I've not tested this, so it may need debugging.

Editted to add:

```
$links = Array();  
$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab    
// grabs the urls from URL  

function Titles($link) {
    $str = file_get_contents($link);    
    if( strlen( $str )>0 ) {    
        preg_match_all( "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $str, $titles );
        if (count($titles) > 1) {
            return $titles[1];   
        }
    }

    return '';
}

$file  = file_get_html($URL); 
foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement)  {     
    $abs_url = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);     
    if (!empty($abs_url)) {
         $links[] = $abs_url; 
    } 
}

$output = Array();

foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
    $output[] = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink));
}
```

(Again, this is very untested)

You generate your list of links; then, step through that list, and for each, get the title of the page. You're doing them one at a time, so it's a lot easier to keep track of what's where.

Comment: there seems to be a parse error where my ?> closing tag is for some reason ?

Comment: You'll need to make sure all the braces are being closed properly. There was a rogue one at the end of my code, which I've just cleaned up.

Comment: sorry, it still returns 1 for some reason :(

Comment: would i have to change my creation of the array at the bottom??

Comment: What do you get if you add a `var_dump($titles)` just after the `preg_match_all` call?

Comment: i get several arrays with all the titles in the correct order, all the exact same.

Comment: Do you want to add them to the question?

Comment: sorry about the delay, i had to put them all in the correct code box

Comment: The function as it now stands is returning the title, as it's supposed to. You're going to have amend the way you're dealing with the return value - I don't know what's on `$links`, for one thing.

Comment: You could just explain it, if it's easier.

Comment: i just want the output from the array_walk in the [title] value

Comment: So you for your page, you'll have multiple entries? Each with the same title but each link will be different?

Comment: no i want, the function to scan the title for each [link] value and then assign the title that it is scanned in the same section but under the [title]

Comment: The Qlick => [link] => "http://www.theqlick.com" [title] => The Qlick for example...